# what should be the query for this?

Tags: sql

how do I swap records in SQL . I have a case in which I have to swap records of one employee to other , for example I have to update like " **A's hat on B's head and B's hat on A's head**" .
Only I need the query , i have the fields.

what should be the best approach for this? Is there any easy query for this ?

Comment: You should go accept some answers for your many question, and put some example data in the question.

Comment: You need to be more specific.  Show your schema, some example tuples, what you have tried, and what you want the result to be.

Comment: You can use procedural language supplied by your RDBMS. Then use a temporary variable just like in any common-purpose language and swap the data.

Comment: Max is right, if you don't accept answers to your questions, eventually people will stop answering you.

Comment: sorry !!! Ok I will do it now ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
declare @hatIdA int
declare @hatIdB int

select @hatIdA = hatId from employees where empID = 'A'

select @hatIdB = hatId from employees where empID = 'B'

update employees set hadId = @hatIdB where empID = 'A'

update employees set hadId = @hatIdA where empID = 'B'
```

I'd do this way...

Answer (score 3):

Example with hats and employees 'A' and 'B', using a [self-join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Self-join) on the employees table for MySQL:

```
UPDATE
    employees AS e1
JOIN 
    employees AS e2 ON (e1.employee_id = 'A' AND e2.employee_id = 'B')
SET
    e1.hat = e2.hat,
    e2.hat = e1.hat;
```

Further reading:

- [Microshell - Swap values in 2 rows SQL](http://www.microshell.com/database/sql/swap-values-in-2-rows-sql/)

Comment: this one is cool ! but how do I do this in SQL , I am using sql 2000